# Mysql recursive query interconnected lines

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I have two tables: lines and points. The line table represents the interconnection between two points.

The line table has:

> idLine idStartPoint idEndPoint ...
>   YL19197 YP004990 YP004991
>   YL19195 YP004989 YP004990
>   YL19199 YP004991 YP004992
>   ...

The points table has:

```
     idPoint  Feed ...
     YP004990   0
     YP004989   0
     YP004991   0
     .......   ...
     YP005214   1
```

Having only the idLine value, I need to go through all lines based on idStartPoint and idEndPoint until there is a point that has the feed value at '1'.

For now I did this (assuming the idLine is YL19197)

- Search for the YL19197 line and bring idStartPoint (YP004990) and idEndPoint (YP004991)
- Generate a query that brings the two lines that are connected to YL19197 (without bringing back YL19197):

> select * from lines where idStartPoint='YP004990' and idLine <>
>   'YL19197'
>
> union select * from lines where idEndPoint='YP004990' and idLine <>
>   'YL19197'
>
> union select * from lines where idStartPoint='YP004991' and idLine
>   <>  'YL19197'
>
> union select * from lines where idEndPoint='YP004991' and idLine <>
>   'YL19197'

This brings me back two lines:

```
idLine idStartPoint idEndPoint

YL19195 YP004989 YP004990

YL19199 YP004991 YP004992
```

But I need all the lines that are interconnected, until I find one that has a point "feed=1."

Graphical representation:

[image: lines-points]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive queries are not supported by MySQL until version 8.0.1.

This should work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r(idLine, idStartPoint, idEndPoint) AS (
  SELECT idLine, idStartPoint, idEndPoint 
  FROM line WHERE idLine='YL19197'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT l.idLine, l.idStartPoint, l.idEndPoint
  FROM r JOIN line l ON l.idStartPoint = r.idEndPoint
  JOIN points p ON p.idPoint = r.idEndPoint 
  WHERE p.feed = 0
)
SELECT * FROM r;
```

Output with the data you should in your question:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+
| idLine  | idStartPoint | idEndPoint |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| YL19197 | YP004990     | YP004991   |
| YL19199 | YP004991     | YP004992   |
+---------+--------------+------------+
```

Your test data doesn't look like it has enough rows to demonstrate termination at the point with feed=1.

If you use a version of MySQL earlier than 8.0.1, you'll have to do it another way. The most straightforward is to write application code to run one query for a line, then check the result if it's the terminal point that you're looking for, and if not, loop and make another query for the next line.